# Circular SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, circular-reference, ssh-tunnel

Is is possible to create a circular SSH Tunnel?

local1 >SSH_TUNNEL> remote1 >SSH_TUNNEL> local1

On "Remote1" I create a TAR that I want to pipe to STDOUT ( - ) ... can I then TAR - . | >SSH_TUNNEL> local1

`ssh user@remote1 "tar -cvf - . | ssh user@local1"`

I've googled and forum'd and googled some more ... I can't seem to find the answer.  Also, I did find references like this:

[SSH Tunnel Complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823759/ssh-tunnel-complex-problem)

But it has low votes and the owner didn't mark it as correct ... I'm not even sure if that applies to my issue.

Any ideas and/or suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: A tunnel is already a two directional pipe, why would you need to duplicate it?

Comment: Perhaps that's my answer ... how do we redirect output from the remote host back to the local host?  Connect remote, do stuff, send that stuff back through the tunnel to the local. -- in this specific case ... connect to remote host, search with FIND, make TAR with FIND output ... then send completed TARBALL back to local host that established the tunnel.

Comment: That is an impressively long time between receiving ans answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, and I know why you might want to do this. The listed command is rather silly, but still ...

```
ssh -R2222:127.0.0.1:22 user@remote1 "tar -cvf - . | ssh user@local1:2222 (whatever)"
```

If you do this more than once you will have public key headaches to cleanup. I don't know any good way around this save editing .ssh/known_hosts every time.

The listed objective is better achieved as

```
ssh user@remote1 "tar -cvf - ." | (whatever)
```